# Internal Server Error (500) for Azure Bot Service or App Service

Tags: .net, azure, artificial-intelligence, botframework, bots

I am getting an Internal Error after deploying my Bot at azure while working fine at emulator.
After deployment and run Test webchannel then get message of "Sorry, My bot is having Code Error". 
Where as when i see an issue out there it shows an Internal Server error 500.
After this when remove these lines

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
```

then it will work fine everywhere using below mentioned code:-

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
  Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("You sent me a message");
  await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

The Bot Dialogs working fine at Emulator just facing an issue at Azure, Can any one please guide me regarding this? because i wanting to use Bot Dialogs.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sheikh! 500s are kinda hard to diagnose, but there are some troubleshooting steps we can take. First, what kind of state store are you using? Second, when you use test in 1web chat, what errors come up in the developer console (pushing F12)?

Comment: if possible, put a link to the full source code that can show the exception. I used to have such but in my case I was using the Attachments and locally the collection was set to an empty array and remotely it was null and that thrown an Error 500.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik this is simple code which i attached over there, i am getting an error because of Dialogs, if i removed it... this works fine for me.

@J

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Error is simple and no more details, where as i am using simple Root state

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?